# How to Ignore fields used by custom annotation in swagger

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger

I have a custom annotation and use that in controller class for modify data. I need to ignore that in swagger dashboard.

Custom Annotation :

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CustomAnnotation(
     val fieldName: String,
     val sourceType: String
)
```

Api Function :

```
@GetMapping("/")
fun get(
        @PathVariable input: String,
        @CustomAnootation id: String
): Model = modelService.get(input)
```

I have a lot of api that use CustomAnnotataion in controller class, and i want ignore all of them without use @ApiIgnore or @Hidden for every one.